# How to get all the implementation classes of an interface in Java?

Tags: java

I am making a Java program. The version of JDK is 1.8. I need to let the user implement an interface, and the implemented method will be called automatically.
However, I don’t know how to get the implementation class based on the interface.

I tried Java SPI, but the user needs to write file in resource. But I want to implement the interface without any operation.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: The answer is still SPI. Have the user provide a reference to the class. There are libraries that can make doing so trivial, such as google's `auto-service`.

Comment: Are you using spring?

Comment: I can't confirm if the consumer is using spring